# Sort numeric range columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sorting, range

Can I sort two columns separately in a query so that both are in perfect acceding order?

given example:

**QUERY**

```
select 
  ad.escore,
  ad.mscore,
  round(sum(ps.cnt) / sum(n.cnt) * 100,1) as percent
from 
(
  select 
    account_no,
    to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 5, '9999') || '-' || to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 14, '9999') as escore,
    cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1 as text) || '-' || cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25 as text) as mscore
  from account_details
) ad
join 
(
  select custno, count(*) as cnt
  from paysoft_results 
  where result = 'Successful' 
  and resultdate >= '13/08/2014' 
  and resultdate <= '12/19/2014'
  group by custno
) ps on ps.custno = ad.account_no
join 
(
  select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
  from naedo 
  and start_date >= '13/08/2014' 
  and start_date <= '12/19/2014' 
  group by customer_code
) n on n.customer_code = ad.account_no
group by ad.escore, ad.mscore;
```

**RETURN RESULT**

[image]

**REPORT GRID**

[image]

IS it possible to have both the columns and the rows in perfect ascending order?

Comment: Try putting an ORDER BY after the GROUP BY at the end of the query, with the fields you want ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns and rows are actually sorted in your report. You are sorting string values where '51-75' is greater then '101-125', so it looks wrong.

You need to format '51-75' as '051-075' to make it sorted according to numeric ranges.